# shared_preferences not working in release mode even after building with --no-shrink flag

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, release, flutter-sharedpreference

I am using 'shared_preferences' plugin in my flutter project. The problem is that the app is working as expected in debug mode but not working correctly in release mode. I have tried building with the --no-shrink flag also but still it does not work. Following is the code snippet where I am implementing the logic:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String notificationID = prefs.getString("notificationID") ?? "";
String messageID = message.data['id'];
if (notificationID == messageID.toString()) {
   print("Notification has been displayed in the past");
} else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help first run
`flutter build apk --no-shrink`
`flutter build appbundle --no-shrink`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763638/11519962

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it did not work

Comment: Hey Ibrahim, did you find a solution yet, @IbrahimRehman?