# Shared Preferences is not working on release mode even with --no-shrink

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

You probably saw this question before, but I am still not able to find an answer. Everything works fine in debug mode, but when trying to build the app in release mode, the shared preferences don't work. Here is what I've tried

`flutter build apk --no-shrink`
`flutter build appbundle --no-shrink`

I know there are already questions out there, but the answers don't work for me: [SharedPreferences not instantiating in release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033700/sharedpreferences-not-instantiating-in-release-build/63763638#63763638)

Comment: have you try to upgrade your shared_preference package?

Comment: Try to clean your project 'flutter clean' and after that 'flutter build app --no-shrink'

Comment: Could you update your question adding a snippet of code showing how you instantiate and use the SharedPrefs ? Any log would also help

Comment: This question requires more info like a minimal and complete sample code, The version of flutter, and shared_preferences that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I called the getter/setter too quickly when the instance of SharedPreferences was still null and has not been initialized yet.
See the answer of this post for reference:
[Flutter: Shared Preferences null on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957815/flutter-shared-preferences-null-on-startup)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have fully set up Facebook login, Google login, Apple login if you have one of them.
If you don't have them check any pub that you haven't fully set up, and remove un used pubs.